# Downloading a GeoJSON file from ORS API Call - JS Vanilla

Tags: javascript, json

I'm hunting high and low to try and get some answers to this.

I'm trying to make an API call to OpenRouteService to generate a geoJSON response.

I have a download button that calls the function `buildPolygon`.

How can I get the function to download the API call as a geoJSON file in JS vanilla?

```
function buildPolygon() {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('POST', "https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/isochrones/driving-car");
    
    request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json, application/geo+json, application/gpx+xml, img/png; charset=utf-8');
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'My_Key_Here');
    
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState === 4) {
        console.log('Status:', this.status);
        console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
        console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
      }
    };

    var coordstext = document.getElementById('coords').value;
    var range = document.getElementById('mileage2metres').value;
    var resID = document.getElementById('restoid').value;
    var rangetype = document.getElementById('polygontype').value;
    var rangetime = document.getElementById('drivetime').value;
    
    if (document.getElementById('drivemileage').checked) {
    const body = '{"locations":[['+coordstext+']],"range":['+range+'],"id":"'+resID+'","range_type":"'+rangetype+'"}}';
    } else { 
    const body = '{"locations":[['+coordstext+']],"range":['+rangetime+'],"id":"'+resID+'","range_type":"'+rangetype+'"}}';
    };

    request.send(body);
}
```

I've not been able to find a solution to pass the data to be able to download a file.